# Showing and hiding object in tableViewCustomCell

Tags: swift, tableview, custom-cell

In my custom cell I have button which tagged in cellForRowAtIndexPath like this:

```
cell.downloadButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

By clicking on this button I want it to be hidden and another to be shown. How should I contact with specific cell knowing only tag of it's button?

Comment: More detail would be useful, what's the context?

Comment: the context that I have few buttons in custom cell and by clicking on first I want it to be hidden and another to be shown, so I dont know how to contacts to button I want to show

Comment: Posting the code for the custom cell would be helpful to see what you already have.

Comment: I have let a = sender.tag, (sender as! UIButton).hidden = true; was it helpful?

Comment: Post the whole class, or at least the function with that in it.

Comment: I updated my question for you guys, but it seems like you laugh at me. Which string was more helpful? "@IBAction" or function name? I told my problem on words. It does not need code support because problem is not in code

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but that code should work. You don't need the `let`, since you're not doing anything with it, and you can set your parameter to `UIButton` instead of `AnyObject` so you don't have to cast. That being said, I would add a `println("was pressed")` in there to make sure the function is being fired. If not, it's not connected to your button.

Comment: How. Should. I. Contact. To. Another. Button. Which. Is. Declared. As. downloadButton. To. Hide. Or. Show. It. I know that this code working and I saying again that I'm asking to for code fixing but for helping with new code string. Is it so hard to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is hard to understand, the code you have appears to do what you're asking. Do you mean to ask how to get the cell that the button belongs to? If so inside `downloadButtonClicked`, you can get the cell it belongs to with `sender.superview` or `sender.superview.superview` and so on depending on how many superviews the button has. An example would look like this:

```
@IBAction func downloadButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    let cell = sender.superview.superview as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.downloadButton.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: That's great, exactly what I need. congratulations with understanding hard understanding question :)